# after upgrading to rails 5, I'm getting an invalid CSRF token error when trying to log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using devise for authentication, but after I upgraded to rails 5 from rails 4 I cannot log in even though CSRF token is inside the request.

here is the server log I'm seeing:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-04-02 15:27:09 +1100
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"q3Ui2rNEIIuRcpNxpbhbIxYLWuYcfd4FxBzIHKgBvdFLUZ96gTIJSQ37kfziG82Vg77NHfdvEkIrThfG6ySpiQ==", "user"=>{"email"=>"xxx", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}}

  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'xxx' ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `current_sign_in_at` = '2019-04-02 03:46:49', `sign_in_count` = 16, `updated_at` = '2019-04-02 03:46:49' WHERE `users`.`id` = 2
   (2.2ms)  COMMIT
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'xxx' ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `last_sign_in_at` = '2019-04-02 03:46:49', `sign_in_count` = 17 WHERE `users`.`id` = 2
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
```

Obviously, when I skip the authenticity token verification the problem is going away.

Comment: Does [this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#protect-from-forgery-now-defaults-to-prepend-false) help?

Answer (score 2):

After digging around a bit I found this [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2734#issuecomment-207867791) thread and specifically [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/4033/files):

> For Rails 5, note that `protect_from_forgery` is no longer prepended to the `before_action` chain, so if you have set `authenticate_user` before `protect_from_forgery`, your request will result in "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity." To resolve this, either change the order in which you call them, or use `protect_from_forgery prepend: true`.

so the problem solved :)

(thanks Mark Merritt who pointed out to the same issue as well)